# XML Overlay Issues

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I was messing around with some XML code in Android studio and ran into this problem.
[image]

As you can see, the layout looks alright on the right side, but on the left it is not showing anything.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent">



    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="#ffd200"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>




<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_sell"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

        tools:context="brainyapps.com.zotbooks.SellActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:text="Select Image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:minHeight="25dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:id="@+id/isbn"
            android:hint="ISBN"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/isbn"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/isbn"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/isbn"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:hint="Price"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Switch
            android:text="Negotiable?"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/negotiable"
            android:switchPadding="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/price"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textOn="Yes"
            android:textOff="No" />
        <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="Condition"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ratingBar"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/course"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/course"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
                android:paddingTop="57dip" />

            <RatingBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />
        </TableRow>
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/negotiable"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.08"
            android:minHeight="30dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/course"
            android:hint="Course No (ex. 61A)"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextDetails"
            android:hint="Details"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:minHeight="85dp" />

    </LinearLayout>



    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

This is my XML code for this. I do not understand what can cause such a problem. I have tried running the application, it is also detecting text fields, but is not displaying them. FAB works perfectly.

Please Help!

UPDATED CODE:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="brainyapps.com.zotbooks.BookDetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:id="@+id/activity_sell"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

                    tools:context="brainyapps.com.zotbooks.SellActivity"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <Button
                        android:text="Select Image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                        android:minHeight="25dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:hint="Name"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                        android:id="@+id/isbn"
                        android:hint="ISBN"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:inputType="number" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/isbn"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/isbn"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/isbn"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:id="@+id/price"
                        android:hint="Price"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />

                    <Switch
                        android:text="Negotiable?"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/negotiable"
                        android:switchPadding="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/price"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:textOn="Yes"
                        android:textOff="No" />
                    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Condition"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ratingBar"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/course"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/course"
                            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
                            android:paddingTop="57dip" />

                        <RatingBar
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />
                    </TableRow>
                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/spinner"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/negotiable"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.08"
                        android:minHeight="30dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/course"
                        android:hint="Course No (ex. 61A)"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editTextDetails"
                        android:hint="Details"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:minHeight="85dp" />



                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                    app:backgroundTint="#ffd200"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                    android:id="@+id/submit"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/book_detail_container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/book_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: An `AppBarLayout` should not be the root `View` for the whole layout. You want the `CoordinatorLayout` as the root `View`.

Comment: I tried that but still the same problem :/

Comment: Update your post. We can't tell what's wrong if we can't see it.

Comment: @MikeM. I have updated the code.

Comment: OK, here's the thing. `AppBarLayout` is for the toolbar area at the top of a layout. You've got a bunch of stuff crammed in there that shouldn't be. The main content should go after it.

Comment: Thanks! That works!